# Why is building/splicing F# quotations so slow?

Tags: performance, f#, quotations

It seems that building quotations via `<@ @>` syntax is painfully inefficient. For example creating a list of integers

```
let q1 = List.foldBack (fun n acc -> <@ n :: %acc @>) [1..100000] <@ [] @>
Real: 00:00:05.714, CPU: 00:00:05.937, GC gen0: 234, gen1: 47, gen2: 1
```

Not only does the above code run very slowly but memory performance is also bad

In contrast the following is faster but still poor memory-wise

```
let q2 = 
    let (NewUnionCase (cons, [_;NewUnionCase (nil, [])])) = <@ [1] @>
    List.foldBack (fun n acc -> Expr.NewUnionCase(cons, [ <@ n @>; acc])) [1..100000] (Expr.NewUnionCase(nil, []))
Real: 00:00:02.352, CPU: 00:00:02.343, GC gen0: 296, gen1: 10, gen2: 0
```

Finally, using plain old `Expr` is significantly better (still not as fast as I would have hoped though)

```
let q3 = 
    let (NewUnionCase (cons, [_;NewUnionCase (nil, [])])) = <@ [1] @>
    List.foldBack (fun n acc -> Expr.NewUnionCase(cons, [ Expr.Value(n, typeof<int>); acc])) [1..100000] (Expr.NewUnionCase(nil, []))
Real: 00:00:00.370, CPU: 00:00:00.375, GC gen0: 8, gen1: 3, gen2: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, I tried to define my own `Expr`-like union type and see how fast that would be:

```
type MExpr = 
  | MUnionCase of Reflection.UnionCaseInfo * A list
  | MValue of int * System.Type
  | MUnit
```

Now, we can compare just the creation of the DU objects and lists, with the actual expression building.

```
List.foldBack (fun n acc -> 
  MUnionCase(cons, [MValue(n, typeof<int>); acc])) [1..100000] MUnit
// ~30ms

List.foldBack (fun n acc -> 
  Expr.NewUnionCase(cons, [ Expr.Value(n, typeof<int>); acc])) 
    [1..100000] (Expr.NewUnionCase(nil, []))
// ~200ms
```

The reason why `NewUnionCase` is slower is that, when you're creating a quotation, the function also type-checks the quotation to make sure that the result is well typed. This involves checking the number of arguments and their types. You can see [what's going on from the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/ed9b9b7df908bbc2b90e46de27dc05678a6d787a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs#L848).

Could you use an array instead of list? The following takes only about ~45ms, because there is a lot less allocation and the type checking is also easier:

```
Expr.NewArray(typeof<int>, List.init 100000 (fun i -> 
  Expr.Value(i, typeof<int>)))
```

If you want to construct a quotation that produces a list, you can still do that:

```
let a = Expr.NewArray(typeof<int>, List.init 100000 (fun i -> 
  Expr.Value(i, typeof<int>)))
<@ List.ofArray (%%a) @>
```

Comment: I am still unsure why splicing is significantly slower. Arrays are not practical here for me because I need to use unification and arrays are fixed length. For the same reason cons list must be well formed, so <@ List.ofArray .. @> is out of the question.

Comment: Also, many times I've encountered stackoverflows, which leads me to the suggestion that traversing trees are not tail-recursive. Couldn't the quotations library benefit from continuations or similar?

Comment: @alakfq I'm sure there are ways to optimize this, but I'm feeling that you might be better off not using quotations in the first place. What is the actual problem that you're solving?

Comment: Hard to say in a few words but quotations offer a potentially powerful tool for metaprogramming, code analysis and AI, things that are natural in Scheme or Clojure. It might be possible to work around but [ReflectedDefinition] is potentially awesome and not replicated. Plus quotations are a cornerstone for Type Providers. Ever so often I hit a brick wall. Also I'm just interested in what's going on behind the scenes. The splicing benchmark surprised me.

Comment: F# quotations are great for some things, but they won't give you the full flexibility of macros in LISP-like languages. More likely, I would approach the problem by definining my own domain-specific language using discriminated unions. Or just use a LISP-like language...

Comment: I'm not aware of any LISPy languages for .NET, do you know of any?

Comment: No, I don't know of a LISP-like language for .NET. If that's a constraint, then I guess F# is your best option - but I would not try to use it as if it was LISP.

Comment: I believe you are right, it looks like there is a gap in the market. On the original question do you have any idea why <@ head::tail @> is so much slower than Expr.NewUnionCase?